# Efficiently modifying sub-documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document:

```js
{
  A1: 1,
  A2: 2,
  A3: [
    { test: "B1", value: 3 },
    { test: "B2", value: 4 }
  ]
}
```

I would like to update the document to look like this:

```js
{
  A1: 10,                       // "A1" becomes 10
  A2: 2,                        // "A2" remains unchanged
  A3: [
    { test: "B1", value: 30 },  // "value" becomes 30 where "test" is "B1"
    { test: "B2", value: 4 },   // "value" remains unchanged where "test" is "B2"
    { test: "B3", value: 50 }   // a new sub-document is added
  ],
  A4: 60                        // "A4" is added with the value of 60
}
```

If I didn't have the array of sub-documents, and I only needed to change the `A*` values, I could simply use a `$set`, which would both set the value of `A1` and add `A4`:

```js
{ $set: { A1: 10, A4: 60 } }
```

How can I apply all the changes described above atomically and with the minimum amount of queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially tried to use only one query to update the documents, but it appears that you cannot run two operations on any given array within the same query. This is the error that I got:

```
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 16837,
                "errmsg" : "Cannot update 'A3.0.value' and 'A3' at the same time
"
        }
})
```

Then I decided to split that query in 2 parts and managed to get the desired functionality.

In the first query, I searched for all the documents that have an object with the test value of `B1`, within the `A3` array and set the value for that particular object to 30.

Also, since the value of `A1` changes by default, I updated its value and also added `A4` since it is a new element.

Then I specified the `multi` parameter in order to update all the documents that match the criteria

```
db.collection.update({ A3: { $elemMatch: { test: "B1"} } }, 
                           { $set: { "A3.$.value": 30, A1: 10, A4: 60 }}, 
                           { multi: true});
```

In the second query, I searched for all the documents that have an existing `A3` array and pushed the new object.

```
db.collection.update({ A3: { $exists: true }}, 
                           { $push: { A3: { test: "B3", value: 50 }}}, 
                           { multi: true});
```